strjoin compatibility in Matlab and Octave
For the function strjoin, it would be good the same code could run on Matlab and Octave. The parameters for strjoin are almost the same. The difference is in Matlab it requires a vector [], and in Octave it requires a cell {}. Is there any better way than to check the "OCTAVE_VERSION" to switch?
strjoin(["mat" "lab"]);

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html
strjoin({"oc" "tave"});

https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/strjoin.html
OCTAVE_VERSION

https://docs.octave.org/v4.0.3/How-to-distinguish-between-Octave-and-Matlab_003f.html

strjoin in MATLAB also takes a cell array of character vectors, as you can read in the documentation you linked.
In MATLAB, traditionally, a “string” was a character vector (an array where the elements are characters). These are created with ': 'foo'. To put more than one together in the same variable, you need to put them in a cell array. Octave, seeing that " was unused in MATLAB syntax, took it to mean the same thing as '. Hence you can create a character vector in Octave as 'foo' or as "foo".
Later, MATLAB introduced the string object. This is created with " ("foo"), and can be made into an array (a string array) with [] just like numbers. Indexing works differently for this object, and there are many advantages in usability. Octave has no way of replicating this without breaking a lot of existing Octave code, so there is no string in Octave.
Thus, if you want to make code that works in both Octave and MATLAB, always use the single quotes ' for your strings. strjoin({'foo' 'bar'}) works in both.

fwiw, you can index individual characters in a MATLAB string, you just have to use curly braces str="foo"; str{1} % = 'f'

@Wolfie I did not know that. That's ugly! I convert to char vector to index individual characters.

Indeed, I think of the indexing as if it's a cell, because the semantics are similar with parentheses or curly braces returning the same or internal data respectively. I typically throw a cellstr() at function inputs which might be strings or chars and treat everything afterwards as a cell of char arrays.

@Wolfie The problem is that MATLAB doesn’t allow indexing with arr(i){j}, only the other way around. And that doesn’t make sense with a string array to index a particular letter.

Thanks, I did not know the difference of 'string' and "string". Now it works fine.

@Cris confusingly you can do str = ["string","array"]; str{1}(1) % = 's' too, because str{1} = 'string'; % char. Agreed this is all pretty ugly, curly braces on a string array is the char of the first string, but curly braces on a scalar string returns the char of the first letter... mad

@Wolfie What? That is very confusing! That reverses the meaning of the two types of brackets! I would downvote your comment if it was possible to do so. That's how much I dislike that syntax.
